# Best normalization method for judge scores?

Tags: multilevel-analysis, normalization

I am working on a dataset in which 10 judges each rate 5 teams (50 teams total). Since each judge differ greatly in their evaluation criteria (i.e., some of them overrate and others underrate), I am looking for a standardization method to account for such difference. Currently, I am considering one of the following:

1. calculating z-score: (x - mean) / sd
2. dividing x by group mean: x / mean

Statistically, which method should be preferred? Or is there a better method available?

Comment: What would be the aim of such normalization? What is your research question?

Comment: I want to use team performance (scored by judge) as an outcome variable, but since each judge may have tendency to overrate or underrate, I want to make sure the team score accounts for such difference. I think normalization on judge score would be helpful.

Comment: Why not use a multilevel model, since scores are nested within judges?

Comment: Since we have about 10 judges, using multilevel model for analysis will lose a good amount of df. I think normalizing score could solve this issue, but do correct me if I am wrong.